# Python Script for creating CSV for pay period

Tags: python, csv

I am generating a python script to quickly create a csv table to record employee pay data.

The following table is an example of 2015 pay table for Employee ID 001.  For Pay period 2, or February, period 6 (June), period 9 (September) - we give out bonuses, reflected in the "Amount" column.

```
ID   | Description| Date      | Status | Amount
001  | Pay period | 1/31/2015 |    1   |  50.00
001  | Pay period | 2/28/2015 |    1   | 100.00
001  | Pay period | 3/31/2015 |    1   |  50.00
001  | Pay period | 4/40/2015 |    1   |  50.00
001  | Pay period | 5/31/2015 |    1   |  50.00
001  | Pay period | 6/30/2015 |    1   | 100.00
001  | Pay period | 7/31/2015 |    1   |  50.00
001  | Pay period | 8/31/2015 |    1   |  50.00
001  | Pay period | 9/30/2015 |    1   | 100.00
001  | Pay period | 10/31/2015|    1   |  50.00
001  | Pay period | 11/30/2015|    1   |  50.00
001  | Pay period | 12/31/2015|    1   |  50.00
```

I want to be able to quickly generate a csv with this structure that automatically writes rows for each month, and that takes into account the special bonus pay periods of February, June and September.

My code is this, but I can't get any further to take into account the different treatment of the special months, and how to auto calculate the last day of each month as auto increments:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv

ID = 0
month = 0
year = 2015

with open('Employee.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"',       quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
writer.writerow(['ID', 'description', 'date', 'status', 'amount'])

for month in range(1, 13):
    date = "%d-%02.d-%02.d" % (year, month, 1)
    for install in range(100):
        Pay Period += 1
        writer.writerow([ID(ID), 'Pay period', date, install_fee])
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below uses [`monthrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange) from calendar to get the last day of the month.

I'm not sure what you want to do for bonus months, so I just filled it with `pass` for now.

```
from calendar import monthrange

with open('Employee.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, 
                        delimiter='\t', 
                        quotechar='"',       
                        quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerow(['ID', 'description', 'date', 'status', 'amount'])

    for month in range(1, 13):
        date = "%d-%02.d-%02.d" % (year, month, monthrange(year, month)[1])
        if month in [2, 6, 9]:  # Special months
            pass  # Add bonus
        for install in range(100):
            Pay Period += 1
            writer.writerow([ID(ID), 'Pay period', date, install_fee])
```